# Makefile with files in different folders

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new with makefiles and I'm trying to write one that compiles files from different folders. You can see my files distribution in the output of tree command that I have added to the post:
I want my header files in the includes folder, some library files in srclib, my main source files in src and the generated .o in lib. To start, I have tried recursive makefiles but I'm unable to compile tcp.c because the compiler can't find tcp.h, I'm stuck.

[Output tree command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thd5k.png)

```
.
|-- includes
|   `-- tcp.h
|-- lib
|-- makefile
|-- src
|   |-- cliente.c
|   `-- servidor_preforked.c
`-- srclib
    `-- tcp.c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to indicate where to find the header to your compiler, for *gcc* this is done with the option `-I`

For instance if you produce `a.out` in *lib* your makefile can be :

```
lib/a.out:
    gcc -o lib/a.out -I includes srclib/tcp.c src/cliente.c src/servidor_preforked.c
```

---

To also produces objects in *lib* :

```
all::lib/a.out

GCC = gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wextra

lib/tcp.o : srclib/tcp.c includes/tcp.h
    $(GCC) -c -o lib/tcp.o  -I includes srclib/tcp.c

lib/cliente.o : src/cliente.c includes/tcp.h
    $(GCC) -c -o lib/cliente.o  -I includes src/cliente.c

lib/servidor_preforked.o : src/servidor_preforked.c includes/tcp.h
    $(GCC) -c -o lib/servidor_preforked.o  -I includes src/servidor_preforked.c

lib/a.out : lib/tcp.o lib/cliente.o lib/servidor_preforked.o
    $(GCC) -o lib/a.out -I includes lib/tcp.o lib/cliente.o lib/servidor_preforked.o
```

Example :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ rm lib/*
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ make
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wextra -c -o lib/tcp.o  -I includes srclib/tcp.c
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wextra -c -o lib/cliente.o  -I includes src/cliente.c
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wextra -c -o lib/servidor_preforked.o  -I includes src/servidor_preforked.c
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wextra -o lib/a.out -I includes lib/tcp.o lib/cliente.o lib/servidor_preforked.o
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ ls -l lib
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 8208 févr. 23 18:15 a.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  956 févr. 23 18:15 cliente.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  856 févr. 23 18:15 servidor_preforked.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  840 févr. 23 18:15 tcp.o
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to generate tcp.o in lib, but I can't use -c and -o at the same time so I don't know how to set the object file in the folder that I want. I've tried this: lib/tcp :
 gcc -ansi -pedantic -g -c -o lib/tcp -I includes srclib/tcp.c includes/tcp.h

Comment: @moliverac8 why are you saying `can't use -c and -o at the same time ` ?

Comment: Compilers says so: gcc -ansi -pedantic -g -Wall -c -o lib/tcp -I includes srclib/tcp.c includes/tcp.h
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:11: lib/tcp] Error 1

Comment: @moliverac8 this is very strange, what is your gcc version and on what OS ?. I edited my answer to show a second example

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 and gcc 8.2.0

Comment: @moliverac8 ok I see now, this is because you put `srclib/tcp.c includes/tcp.h` rather than just `srclib/tcp.c`, do not give the header file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can explicitly add folder names to targets and commands as @bruno, but that's a bit like hardcoding, plus adds a bit of duplication. A way to improve that is to use `VPATH` or [vpath function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html#Selective-Search) that fits for that case:

```
vpath %.h includes
vpath %.c src:srclib
vpath %.o lib
```

This tells which directory to search for a particular type of files. For .c files it will search both "src" and "srclib".

Now the rules might look simpler like so:

```
cliente.o : cliente.c tcp.h
    $(GCC) -c -o lib/$@  -I includes $<
```

Note the usage of `$@` and `$<` [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables). In this case `$<` will expand to the first prerequisite path with directory - "lib/cliente.c", and `$@` is just the target name - "cliente.o".

If you write the rules like so you might end up that all your rules look the same, and think about refactoring it further to just a single implicit pattern rule `%.o: %.c`.